# CouchDB, Fauxton - installation of, locating files

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I'm using CouchDB 1.5 on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04. I'm having trouble understanding how the Fauxton app got installed (as I don't recall installing it.)

I found the UI at [myhostip]:5984/_utils/fauxton/ but I can't locate all of the files on disk.  So the questions are:

1) I'm thinking the Ubuntu Software Center installed some sort of package, but wondered if someone could confirm that?

2) Where the application files on disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fauxton is a part of couchdb, in fact it is the default user interface for 2.0. Most likely your fauxton is in

`/usr/local/share/couchdb/www/fauxton`

to find out for sure open your your config file

`http://localhost:5984/_utils/config.html`

and look for

`__utils` in `httpd_global_handlers` section and it will tell you where couchdb utilities are installed. In the utilities directory you should see a `fauxton` folder which contains the fuaxton files.

Don't worry though no third party installed it. It is a part of couchdb package. [Here is the repo on github](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton).

Comment: Thanks. On my host, it is actually /usr/share/couchdb/www/fauxton. What is still puzzling however is this: that directory contains very few files. In particular is seems to be missing many, many JS files that comprises the fauxton app. I'm puzzled as to where those files reside and how the couch server serves them.

Answer (score 1):

Went further based on guidance from @Akshat; it turns out that the Fauxton application code *was* on disk in /usr/share/couchdb/www/fauxton/js in a file named require.js.  All code and templates were there, minified and munged.